# Relative Referencing in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have a table with some missing values. For each row, I need to fill the blanks based on the nearest value present on the right side of the blank.

Example would be - [image]

I could find a block of code that did the trick -

`ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlBlanks).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(COUNTA(RC[1]:RC[" & ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count & "]),RC[1],"""")"`

The problem is is cannot figure out this - RC[" & ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count & "].
Although I know what it is doing (we are checking from the right cell onwards to the last column of usedrange if there is any value in any of the cells), this syntax is completely new for me. I an not able to understand how this relative referencing is working and why are there 2 ampersand within the quotes.

Also, does `RC[1]` mean that the values start getting filled from the right end of the table? Because if we suppose the cell - first row, fifth column - we see that the right adjacent cell is also empty so `RC[1]` should give blank. But that will not happen if the execution starts from the last column itself and then moves leftwards.

Comment: The ampersands are outside the quotes. Ampersands are used in Excel formulas to build strings. If you're confused by `ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count`, what did you get when you googled it?

Comment: You can do this easily in Power Query (available in Excel 2010+).  Merely `Transpose`, `Fill Up`, and `Transpose` back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ampersand is used to concatenate two strings.

In this:

```
"=IF(COUNTA(RC[1]:RC[" & ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count & "]),RC[1],"""")"
```

You have this:

```
"=IF(COUNTA(RC[1]:RC["
```

Concatenated with this (which is being implicitly type-cast to a string):

```
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
```

Concatenated with this:

```
"]),RC[1],"""")"
```

Note that this will also work:

```
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlBlanks).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[1]<>"""",RC[1],"""")"
```

All the formula is saying is "If the cell to the right of this cell has a value in it, then use that value. Otherwise leave this cell empty".

The original formula is just saying "If there are more than one empty cell between the cell to the right of this cell and the right edge of the used range, then use the cell to the right of this cell".

Comment: Am I right about the assumption in the last paragraph?

Comment: You can think about it that way, but I think it's more helpful to think that each formula must consider the result of a formula in any cell it references before it resolves. So if a cell a formula references is "empty" but it contains a formula, then we need to check what the formula will put in the cell before we can really consider it empty. It's more about dependency than where it starts per se.